# Is there a PyTorch tensor function that reduces dimension in regular patterns

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Sorry for the poor wording of the title. What I wanted to do is like this:
[image: example]
Matrix 1 is the original matrix, and matrix 2 is matrix 1 but with every even columns and rows taken out. Matrix 3 is matrix 1 but only has 1 (mod 3) columns and rows. Matrix 4 is the same, with 1 (mod 4) columns and rows. Matrix 5 has 1 (mod 2) columns and all rows.

Is there a PyTorch function that manipulates tensors in this way that is fast and can utilize the GPU? This is sort of like MaxPool2d, however I just need the first value and not the max. If there aren't any functions like that, is there a way to do it manually but still fast?

Comment: Isn’t this just slicing?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to have for loops and selecting individual columns and rows out, because that will be very slow. I am looking for an internal function that can do this quickly

Comment: I know. Use slices. That wouldn’t involve for-loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrix 5 is the easiest to show, because you only need to slice along one dimension. But you can slice along both to get the other results.

```
matrix5 = matrix1[, ::2]
```

This notation takes every second column, starting at the zeroth.

Comment: Now the question seems dumb. It's just that I have never used that last slicing index before. Thank you

Comment: Yes I will, it won't allow me to mark resolved just yet